# path name contains null byte for image url while existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, open-uri

I'm using the following code to get the width of image using [Dimensions Gem](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dimensions/1.3.0).

```
file_path = "http://localhost:3000/uploads/resize/avatar/25/ch05.jpg"
width = Dimensions.width(open(file_path).read)
```

When I put the image `url` in `url bar` it renders the image in browser. what I'm trying to do is to get the width of image. so can anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So your issue is that `Dimensions` requires a file path to determine the width of the image. `open` will return a `StringIO` and `open(...).read` will return a `String` both will fail when using `File.open`.

`Dimensions#width`

```
def width(path)
  io_for(path).width
end
```

`Dimensions#io_for`

```
def io_for(path)
  Dimensions(File.open(path, "rb")).tap do |io|
    io.read
    io.close
  end
end
```

To work around this you can download the image to a `Tempfile` and then use that path to pass to `Dimensions.width` like so

```
 path = "http://localhost:3000/uploads/resize/avatar/25/ch05.jpg"
 t = Tempfile.new                 # you could add a name but it doesn't matter
 t.write(open(path).read)         # write the image to the Tempfile
 t.close                          # must close the file before reading it
 width = Dimensions.width(t.path) # pass the Tempfile path to Dimensions
 t.unlink                         # deletes the Tempfile
```

We can make this look a little cleaner like so:

```
def get_width_of_url_image(url)
  t = Tempfile.new.tap do |f| 
    f.write(open(url).read)
    f.close
  end
  width = Dimensions.width(t.path)
  t.unlink and width
end

get_width_of_url_image("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
#=> 272
```